# Reusable functionality in multiple views

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on a Codeigniter project and need to use the same bit of functionality in multiple views.

Here is a basic outline of what I want to do:

In several areas of my site, I need to display some info about users. This info includes a profile image, a rating and a link to send email or view reviews.

The display has to be modified dynamically.ex; Sometimes the link to send email is not available because of various settings.

Now, some pages may have just one of these, some pages may have several.

So what I want to do is build a small component that can be loaded, fed the users info then handle building the display.

My first thought was to build a helper, but I have read that including helpers in views is not good MVC practice. So what other technique is there in CI to do something like this?

take care,
lee

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to use multiple view sections in multiple views and don't want to have to keep repeating yourself. You can check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15593888/1592648 it's an example of creating a template view which loads the common views in it and allows you to pass the data to it while also loading a custom view within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a partial view and load that in to the main view as a chunk of HTML.

```
// In Controller
$data['user_info_box'] = $this->load->view('partials/user_info', $settings, true);

$this->load->view('main_view', $data);
```

Then use that (`$user_info_box`) on your main view.

Comment: Thank. The only problem is that it is sometimes needed multiple times and with different data. I am looking at using a library at the moment.

Comment: You can use this multiple times, you have to change the `$settings` array with your relevant data and get whatever the HTML you need and pass that to your main view.